# Calling the action from ForegroundService

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I'm writing an emergency application that, when a button is pressed on an bluetooth SOS device, performs several actions (calling and sending sms to several contacts). Bluetooth is listened to in ForegroundService so that the user can work on the phone without interference.
The idea behind this application is to display the emergency screen unconditionally and perform the appropriate actions after reading that the button has been pressed. And here's where the problem arises - since Android 10, you can't call intentions from background activity.
Looking for solutions, I have not found much. The only code I came across is this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("rating").authority("call").build();
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            i.setData(uri);
                            //i.putExtra("call_ratings_for", call_id);
                            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(i);
```

In the manifest file in the called activity item added:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="rating" />
</intent-filter>
```

Unfortunately, this only works when the application is in the foreground.

Is there any way - official or unofficial - to implement this? I am already losing hope that such an application that is needed can be created at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate what action exactly are you trying to perform? If I remember correctly, some cases are allowed from background or some extra permissions given to apps may allow it to perform actions from background / running as foreground service

Comment: You can try reading this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions if it helps

Comment: @DanBaruch The activity that is called displays a screen with the person's data: personal information, illnesses, medications, etc. It is important that the person who helps the owner of the phone has access to this information. In the second place, the activity sends SMS messages to three contacts saved in the application with the location. The last point is to make calls one by one to the three contacts. 
I know that sending SMS can be implemented. Making a call was also achieved by me using TelecomManager, But I need to do some tests to make sure this way will work on all devices.

Comment: @DanBaruch As a last resort, I'll quit showing the data, but I'd really hate to do that.

Comment: Well, as for personal data you can write it to a file and as soon as the user will open the app, it will read from that file and show the data, does this helps?

Comment: And yes and no - provided that the owner of the phone does not set a screen lock. In that case, the helper will not be able to get to this data without the help of the phone owner, which may not always be possible.

Comment: I see. Well, maybe you can change lock screen settings? upon emergency write specific text to the lock screen? Like where you can write down owner's name / phone number and things like that. Also, are you planning on putting this app in the store eventually or is it for personal use? Because if it's for personal you can elevate some of your permissions using ADB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 ideas that you can look at:

- The first is [`CompanionDeviceManager`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing). If your app is associated with a companion device (and this sounds exactly like your situation), the app should be able to launch an `Activity` in response to some action on the companion device.
- The second idea is giving your app `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. If your app has this permission, your `Service` should be able to launch an `Activity` even if it is in the background.